# How to Verify the integrity of the Google Identity Platform in C# with Google.Apis.Auth.AspNetCore3?

Tags: c#, authentication, firebase-authentication, google-identity

I have set up "Google Identity Platform" and can obtain the access token via firebase-ui web using following code snippet:

```
 user.getIdToken().then(function (accessToken) {
    console.log(accessToken);
  });
```

Now I need to Authenticate users in my ASP NET CORE backend by verifying the access token but I couldn't find any sample.

Is it possible to do it via Google.Apis.Auth.AspNetCore3 library? What is the best solution for it?

**Note:** I don't want to call the tokeninfo endpoint for every request.

Comment: Have you refereed to this [Stackoverlow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60842499/google-apis-oauth-net-core-3-1) and [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/google-logins?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Comment: @SandeepVokkareni I had read that, no help. However I encountered many other problems such as multi-domain and UI customization, M2M server and there is not enough documentation, I ended up using AWS Cognito.

Answer (score 1):

Google.Apis.Auth.AspNetCore3 is not needed. just add the following code:

```cs
        builder.Services
            .AddAuthentication()
            .AddJwtBearer("GoogleIdentityPlatformScheme", bearerOptions =>
            {
                bearerOptions.Authority = "https://securetoken.google.com/FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID";
                bearerOptions.Audience = "FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID";
            });
```